# How to specify range to iterate through an array in ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to remove an application on a remote node using ansible. Below is my playbook. How do i provide a range to the uninstall task to repeat till no packages are left.

### ---

```
 hosts: all



 tasks:
 - name: check-packages
  shell: rpm -qa | grep -e "^\(HPOpr\|HPE\|HPOv\|HPBsm\|MIB2Policy\|HPOMi\)"
  register: output

- name: uninstall
  shell: rpm -e   {{ output.stdout_lines.0 }}   --nodeps
```

I tried with range operator

```
   shell: rpm -e   {{ output.stdout_lines[:40] }}   --nodeps
```

But it was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- name: uninstall
  package:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  with_list: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
```

Or if you use Ansible 2.5 or newer, replace `with_list` with `loop`.

You can also do it in one go:

```
- name: uninstall
  package:
    name: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
    state: absent
```

- [Documentation on loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)
- [Documentation for the package module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html)
- [Documentation on filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like charm. I was having this misconception that package module will only work for RPM :-) .

Comment: The `package` module is the generic one and should be preferred, but there is also an `rpm` and a `yum` module if you need to do specific tasks.